# Generating PDF's or HTML emails using Backbone/Marionette views & models

Tags: backbone.js, pdf-generation, html-email, marionette, backbone-views

A very common requirement is to download the data displayed on the screen as a PDF file or 'mail-a-friend' function that emails the data to the user specified email address.

I'm using Backbone and Marionette and would like to get data from my models to be created in email-able format & as a PDF file. In effect, I'd like to email my 'view' (or dump it in pdf file!)

Question:
Is it possible to re-use the screen templates to render the same item as a email (and/or dump it into a PDF file)?

I've seen other options like jspdf.com, however, using it would mean creating another format for emails/pdfs afresh!?

I've attempted to put together a answer below, but still looking for any plugin or lib that can make life easier to create PDF or html emails.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was by creating new or re-using existing templates (if suitable) and using the models to generate the html from compiled templates (underscore or handlebars). Using the existing view's el to capture dom elements is not a good idea as these many have additional classes attached if using jQuery or other frameworks.

It is also possible to use multiple templates and append the result inside a div so complete representation of data can be produced in emailable or printable format.

I created a div at the end of the doucment which is usually empty:

```
<button id="email-itinerary">Email Details</button>
............
............
............
    <div id="email-dialog">
    </div>
```

On clicking Email Details button, the handler for this button, uses complied templates & models to generate html.

```
var result = "<table border=\"1\">" +
        "<tr>" +
                        //add table headers here
        "</tr>";
var compile = Handlebars.compile($("#email-template").html().trim());
for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++)    {
    result += compile(collection.at(i).toJSON()); //generates <tr>
}
result += "</table>"; //finish table.
  //use more templates to add other data, and append to result variable.
  //Finally add the html to div
            $("#email-dialog").empty();
    $("#email-dialog").append($.parseHTML(result));
    $("#email-dialog").dialog({
          title: "Hotels - at a glance",
          modal: true,
          height: 550,
          width: 1000,
        });
```

PDF: I'm still to figure out the best solution for PDF generation.